# Why github actions run cargo command not found?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

First , I use `runs-on: self-hosted`, and most command, like printf, cp and other, like:

```yaml
- run: cp "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/run_bin" "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/$BIN_PATH/"
```

But, some command, like cargo, it error with `cargo not found`, but my ubuntu has already install it, and work fine.

```
- run: cargo build //error: command not found
```

But some command like pm2, it work with actions.

```
- run: pm2 ls //works
```

I really don't want to use github action plugins like `actions-rs/toolchain`, it really very very very slow!

```
  Updating crates.io index
   Compiling libc v0.2.112
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.36
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.2
   Compiling syn v1.0.84
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling autocfg v1.0.1
   Compiling memchr v2.4.1
   Compiling log v0.4.14
...
...
```

It need over 10 minutes every time, even I use `actions/cache@v2` plugin, it is note stable, sometime 3 minutes, sometimes 6 minutes.

I run cargo build command on ssh, everything works fine. and only several minuts each time.

I have has google ti for weeks, it seems everybody want to use plugin from github action market.

Is it the only way to use CI/CD on github?

Is there anyway to CI/CD like gitlab?

Thank you!

Comment: This question does not provide the necessary details to be answerable by anyone or to be useful to anyone else. What GitHub action are you using to try and execute `cargo`? You should provide your complete GitHub Action file, or at least a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing this:

```
$ which cargo
```

then get the path

```
/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin/carg
```

the place it to - run:

```
- run: /home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin/cargo build
```

then works